# javascript function not working with my html form

Tags: javascript

i have an html code for a form and a javascript function that will perform age calculation and populate it in the next page but the calculation is not working. every other field in the form in being displayed in the next page but the calculation is not just working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<script src="text/javascript">

function calculate_age(birth_month,birth_day,birth_year)
{
    var today_date = new Date();
    var today_year = today_date.getFullYear();
    var today_month = today_date.getMonth();
    today_day = today_date.getDate();
    age = today_year - birth_year;

    if ( today_month < (birth_month - 1))
    {
        age--;
    }
    if (((birth_month - 1) == today_month) && (today_day < birth_day))
    {
        age--;
    }
    return age--;
 document.getElementById("myForm").innerHTML = window.calculate_age()
 
}
</script>


<form action="new1.php" method="post" id="myForm">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<br>
Date of Birth:<br>
<input type="date" name="age" id="dob" script="calculate_age">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" onclick="calculate_age(birth_month,birth_day,birth_year)" value="Submit">


</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define "not working".  How specifically does it fail?  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  When you step through this in a debugger, where does it go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
return age--;
    document.getElementById("myForm").innerHTML = window.calculate_age()
```

The statement that makes modification to your DOM element is never reached.

Comment: the first name, last name, and date of birth displays in the the next page, but the the age does not get calculated to display a two digit age value.

Comment: this answer is correct; your function `returns` before it changes the `innerHTML` value.  Also, your calculations look strange.... why do you keep decrementing age?

Comment: please can you correct the code and briefly explain the changes. i am new in js and coding in general.

Comment: @homel15 Remove `return age--;`

Comment: i just removed return age--; but the calculation is still not taking place.

Comment: @homel15 It is. Why are you doing window.calculate_age()? Just set the innerHTML equal to age.

Answer (score 0):

the first answer is absolutely right. additionally, your button's type is "submit". so, when you click that button, first it runs the function, then posts the page, and all your values are lost because the function that calculates age doesn't run after the form is submitted. you have to change the button's type or run the function on window onload. besides, the function that calculates age have compilation errors. the part that changes the innerhtml of the form needs ";" at the end

Comment: how do i make the DOM element reached: return age--;
    document.getElementById("myForm").innerHTML = window.calculate_age()

Comment: first, change the button's type to "button". then, in the function, delete the return statement and change the last statement to document.getElementById('myForm').innerHTML = age; if you need those values at the back end, you have to call that function on window onload

Comment: when i change my button type to "button' and click submit, the result of the form does not move to the next page.

Comment: hence the part "if you need those values at the back-end". let's start from the beginning. your button doesn't work at all. that's because your sending values to the function at your onclick that doesn't exist."onclick="calculate_age(birth_month,birth_day,birth_year)"" notice that those parameters are not defined at anywhere in your code when the button is clicked. if what your trying to do is send those values to the back-end, do some calculations and then calculate the age at the next page, you have to run your function at window.onload.

Comment: and you have to get rid of those function parameters and get the values in the function